# Opening excel file in Pandas with utf8 encoding

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've got a  characters like ä in a big excel data file which i need pandas to pick up. Basically the problem is not with getting this bit of code to work - if i remove the data in my set containing ä  then it works without any encoding parameter. The problem is i dont want to have to remove that data

I am trying to get the following code to work

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\DataCleaning\\book3.xlsx')

frames = {}
for sheet in sheets:
    
    frames[sheet] =pd.read_excel(xls, sheet, encoding = 'sys.getfilesystemencoding()')
```

but am always getting this error

TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

I've spent a while looking and probably because i dont fully understand what i'm doing above here i cant seem to get any of the solutions to work. The script works without the encoding part - but i end up missing a few of these data points with these characters.

Thanks!

Comment: `encoding` is needed on `pd.read_csv` because you’re opening a text file, it’s not necessarily obvious what the encoding is. A complex file type such as `.xlsx` should not have this issue, and indeed [there is no encoding parameter on pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Just remove that parameter, and see if your characters are imported correctly.

Comment: Also tangentially related: you probably never should use `'sys.getfilesystemencoding()'` as a string. Either use the encoding you want, e.g. `'utf-8'`, or the return vaue of that call: `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` (without quotes − it’s not a string but a function that returns a string)

Comment: It mostly works without the encoding paramater - but as i mention above it misses the data with ä and messes up later when trying to locate it

Comment: can you specify what you mean by « it misses data with ä » ? Try to make an example that is [as small as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so a single file with a single sheet, that has maybe only 1 or 2 cells. Show us the contents of that file, what you expect `pd.read_excel` to return, and what you get instead. With all that information someone will be able to help you but without we would have to do a lot of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try pd.read_excel(). It will return a list of dataframes corresponding to xls tabs.